# Magento 2: Call a static block using xml

Tags: magento2, xml, custom, magento2-dev-beta

How i include a static block in a page using xml. For example i created a static block with identifier promo. In magento 1 we include a static block using below code

```
     <block type="cms/block" name="Promo">
          <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo</block_id></action>
     </block>
```

I want to do exactly same in magento 2

Comment: you may follow this http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-create-a-cms-static-block-in-magento-2-0.html

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Promo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

This is equivalent to M1.

Comment: @Ben-Space48, agree

Comment: Can i add **after='-'**  or    **before='-'**  tag in this

Comment: yes you can @VinitKumar

Comment: how to make that block non-cacheable?

Answer (score 18):

Try below code.

Call from Phtml File:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Call from cms page or block:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

Call from Xml File:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: how to make that block non-cacheable

Comment: Call from xml file means are you talking about layout.xml file? if yes then where should we create the layout.xml file is it really layout.xml or layouts.xml or we should go with default.xml?

Answer (score 5):

Call from Xml File worked. 
Change the "block_identifier" from the CMS block created on magento dashboard and add it to layout.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
       <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `Magento\Cms\Block\Block` class is deprecated, you should use:

```
<block name="custom_block_name" class="Magento\Cms\Block\BlockByIdentifier">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="identifier" xsi:type="string">custom_block_identifier</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="news">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">news</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

It works for me!Hope this helps!

Comment: this code works for me too

Answer (score 2):

[image: static Block]
**Above image you can see my block identifier= "product_view_right_sidebar". add below code to your xml file**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_view_right_sidebar">
        <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product_view_right_sidebar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Can i add **after='-'**  or    **before='-'**  tag in this

Comment: @VinitKumar , yes you can use after=''-" or before="-" tag. <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_view_right_sidebar" before='-'>

Answer (score 1):

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="daily_deals" template="bigbazaar.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">daily_deals</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Here `daily_deals` is my CMS block identifier's name. I wish it should work..

Answer (score 1):

You can call CMS block on Magento2 in following 6 ways:-

- Call static block on category page in Magento2
- Display CMS block with Magento 2 widgets
- Insert CMS block into Magento 2 WYSIWYG editor
- Call the CMS block using layout XML
- Add static block from template phtml file in Magento 2
- Show Static Block within another block in Magento2

For calling CMS block on layout, we can use following code -
**Considering your block identifier is - promo.**

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Promo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```