# How to add content to added Block magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I made a block from admin side  `content->block`  And I can add data from admin side in it and add it to a page I know. But How can I add data to it using phtml and xml ? any working example would be highly appreciated as I am confuse and didn't get any example .
Suppose I made a block named 'No-Picture'  using admin side

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a custom block with data in it you will need to use xml's and phtml's in your own custom theme or module.

I gave a really big explenation of it on the next url :

[Implement a custom theme Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200087/implement-a-custom-theme-magento-2)

Knowing and understanding what i said here you can add blocks in 3 different ways. You can add your block by creating it how you think you need to create it. But this limits you to the widgets of Magento and the text editor. You can add that block in a page by using **content->page** and add the static block in your text editor with a button.

If you want to add a block in a custom page you can do so by creating a custom page layout.

Like how i explained here :
[Completely overwrite parent theme layout from the default.xml file of the child theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198229/completely-overwrite-parent-theme-layout-from-the-default-xml-file-of-the-child/199371#199371)

If you want to adjust html or add block in existing containers of Magento on product pages etc you can do so by understanding my first url and then search for the propper xml layout that corresponds to the block in that page. Find its phtml and class trough that xml and adjust those using your own theme or module.

If you want to add data from Magento admin settings you can add a Helper to retrieve that data from the database. Unless you want to retrieve things like products, customers and other lists from Magento which you can retrieve via interfaces.

You have a lot of reading in front of you trough those 2 url's. I won't retype everything 10x so i give you the information via URL.

If you need any help after reading that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your CMS block.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-name" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml"}}
```

Comment: what do you mean ?  suppose I made a phtml file   named   'new.phtml'   and my block name on admin side is   'new'  then how to bind them ?

Comment: add above code in your cms block from admin. Suppose your phtml file is located in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml` , then above code will put the custom.phtml file's data in your cms block.

Comment: If you are creating a module why not just make a custom page template with your module instead of injecting this in your cms block or page? This is such a messy solution

Comment: @SwAt.Be  can you give a small working example what you saying  ? I am not aware of it

Comment: The only way how this would work is when he has a custom module to refer to. So if he has a custom module why wouldn't he make this in his module instead of using the most buggy text editor i have ever seen in any framework.

Comment: @Learner Let me know when you are done reading my url's in my answer so i know you know the basics of Magento. When you are done with that sure i can help you out with an example.

Comment: @SwAt.Be What if he doesn't have a custom module? What if his phtml file is located in any Magento's default module e.g. Magento_Catalog? I just answered what he was looking for.

Comment: Why would you ever refer to a core Magento file? What if Magento removes it or updates it? What if he uses a childblocks template? Which won't work if the parent loads the requireJS. There is 1000* reasons why not to use the core files directly for custom work. Copy , adjust , use then. Magento is not like a Wordpress website where you can do whatever you want. You need to think about what you do. And this platform (stackexchange) is a way to teach new developers to think and understand Magento before they write crappy code. So no , your answer has no added value and is teaching a bad practice

Comment: @DineshYadav  block class is  path to my phtml file ? name is my block name i made on admin side and  template is aswell path to phtml file ? What is class for ?

Comment: @Learner Class is for rendering the template file. If you don't have your custom block class, then you can use this class.